# Keycloak PUT REST 415

Tags: rest, httpclient, keycloak

I am getting the following error message when trying to CALL REST API of Keycloak used `HttpClient`.The code as following:

```java
ServletRequestAttributes servletRequestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

HttpServletRequest request = servletRequestAttributes.getRequest();
String token = request.getHeader("X-Auth-Token");
String url = authUrl + "/admin/realms/fast/users/"+userId+"/reset-password";

CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(); 
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
httpPut.addHeader("Authorization", token);
httpPut.addHeader("Content-Type ", "application/json");


List<NameValuePair>list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "password"));
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value",userPassDO.getNewPassword()));
list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("temporary","true"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity entity;
try {
    entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list,"UTF-8");
    httpPut.setEntity(entity);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = closeableHttpClient.execute(httpPut);
    HttpEntity et = response.getEntity();
    InputStream in = et.getContent();
    int stat=  response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The response after execute put request show an error

```
 "HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type [Server: nginx/1.15.3, Date: Tue, 30 Oct 2018 09:13:03 GMT, Content-Length: 0, Connection: keep-alive] [Content-Length: 0,Chunked: false]"
```

Does anyone have any ideas or encountered this problem?

Comment: I am also getting 415 on keycloak admin API (although a different one). I had posted the query to keycloak user mailing list but did not get any response. http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-October/015922.html

Comment: I sovled this problem,try to set  "Content-Type" like this ,                
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
    entity.setContentType("application/json");  hope it works for you